# Remove array element when subarray has certain values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that contains any number of `subarrays`, each containing exactly two values.

```
i.e: interestArray[[1, 5], [3, 8] ... ]
```

How do I remove say the `subarray` containing the values [3, 8]?

My code is:

```
$('td', container).click(function(){
      if(!$(this).hasClass('purchased') && !$(this).hasClass('manu'))
      {
        var manuId = $(this).parent().children('td:first-child').data('manu-id');
        var typeId = $(this).data('type-id');
        if($(this).hasClass('interest'))
        {
          $(this).removeClass('interest');
          $(this).parent().children('td.manu').removeClass('interest');
          var index = interestArray.indexOf([manuId, typeId]);
          interestArray.splice(index, 1);
        } else {
          $(this).addClass('interest');
          $(this).parent().children('td.manu').addClass('interest');

          interestArray.push([manuId, typeId]);
        }
      //updateSurvey(interestsArray);
      console.log(interestArray)
      }
    })
```

The below section does not work, and simply removes the first `subarray`.

```
var index = interestArray.indexOf([manuId, typeId]);
interestArray.splice(index, 1);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing two arrays in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/comparing-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: Comparing is not filtering/removing elements.

Comment: No, but your main problem is identifying the item you want to remove. Once you've found it, removing it becomes trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a generic approach with your requirements:

```
var arr = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];
var remove = [3,4];

for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i][0] == remove[0] && arr[i][1] == remove[1]) {
    arr.splice(i, 1);
    break;
  }
}

console.log(arr); //=> [[1,2],[5,6]]
```

Comment: You might want to `break;` when you find a match, otherwise loop backwards, in case there's a possibility of multiple matches

Comment: This will skip the second of consecutive matches. (So if you start with `var arr = [[1,2],[3,4],[3,4],[5,6]];`, the output at the end will be `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]` (with the second `[3,4]` still in the list).

Answer (score 1):

For a general approach, you can [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array:

```
var reducedArray = interestArray.filter(function (item) {
    return item[0] != manuId || item[1] != typeId;
});
```

You cannot use `indexOf` because that looks for the identical object (not merely an equivalent one).

If you're running an earlier version of JS that doesn't have `Array.filter`, there's a nice shim on the `filter` doc page linked to above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my personal solution more complete to avoid multiple entry issue and the break; thing seen above, it also avoids an issue if the array is after entry removal (it is jquery based but you can make a regular loop if you feel more comfy with it):

```
    $.each( answers, function( index, value ){
        if (typeof answers[index] != "undefined") 
        {
            if(answers[index]["question_id"]==answer_to_del)
            {
                delete answers[index];
            }
        }

    });
    //Clean answer array from empty values created above
    answers = answers.filter(function(n){ return n != undefined });
```